# How to archive a file with its filename as the archive name?

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm automating transferring a single .DMP file from multiple locations into my server. Each location has its own file with its unique ID.

```
Eg:
Location 1 - Data-1.DMP
Location 2 - Data-2.DMP
Location-20 - Data-20.DMP
```

The files have average sizes of 5MB and so I want to zip it before transferring over SFTP.
I prefer to do it via a BAT file if possible.

And yes I can manually have separate BAT scripts for each location, but I would really like to have a single script file that will work universally.

I managed to achieve this using PowerShell, but because I have mixed Windows OSes, from POSReady 2009, Win 7 and Win 10, setting up PowerShell is a pain specially for the POSReady clients. So, I am really looking for a BAT script way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help as I'm not totally sure what you are attempting to do.  To get the unique number with extension of the file from a batch file you can use the following:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %i in (`dir /b`) do for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=-" %j in (`echo %i`) do echo %j
```

This gets the "*1.DMP, 2.DMP...*"  Hopefully this can point you in the right direction.